# Troubleshoot org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection attempt timed out that only occasionally happens

Tags: postgresql

I have several applications running on tomcat with a local PostgresSQL database. And tomcat occasionally reports the following errors:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection attempt timed out.
```

I am able to connect to the database using other tools such as DBeaver. And this problem looks only happens when several applications are connecting to the database. So I want to know how to troubleshoot this issue. Is there any log in PostgresSQL that I can check?

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL does have logging.  It is very configurable, and we can't tell you how you have it configured.  Common locations are /var/log/postgresql/, and in PGDATA/log/.  However, a connection timeout will probably not be in the postgresql log as it probably never achieved contact with the postgresql server to start with.